# How to update downstream components in a SSIS Dataflow task?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, dts

I have a dataflow task in SSIS Package script. When I am updating an input or output column, I would like to propagate the update in the downstream components. Is this a behaviour that is possible to achieve?

Right now if I update the metadata(delete, change the datatype etc) of a column in the dataflow task, the update is not propagated to the downstream components and I have to delete the component and re-add it to get the metadata updated.

Any thoughts or directions for investigations are welcome!

Comment: For clarification `a dataflow task in SSIS Package script` Do you literally have a "Script Task that creates a dataflow task" or are you saying you have "a Script Component in a Data Flow Task"? If the later, is the Script Component acting as a source, transformation or destination? If acting as Transformation - is it the default synchronous or did you make it asynchronous

Comment: Thank you for the comment. It is a custom made script, called Delta and compares two tables, built in WPF with the DTS library. 
It acts as a transformation step and it is default synchronous. It is a design instance that I'm trying to add an event so when I'm updating a column mapped to an output, the change propagates downstream to other components where the column acts as an input.